# Comparison operator not behaving as expected in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create something that requires a sort of n-back functionality. Here I have recreated something similar with text showing in a random box, and then again showing in a random box, and it is supposed to tell you if it was the same as the previous box (or the same as however many boxes ago you have it set to).

I am using an array and comparing the current box I have pushed to the 0th index in the array with the previous box (the 1 index).

This works fine for me in vanilla Javascript. But in React Native, I don't really understand what is happening.

https://snack.expo.dev/@skjones90/58123f

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [box, setBox] = useState(0)
  const [same, setSame] = useState("")
  const [boxesArr, setBoxesArr] = useState([])
  const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false)

  function start() {
    setHasStarted(true)

    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) ) + 1;

    setBox(num)

    setBoxesArr((prev) => {
      return [num, ...prev]
    })

    checkPrevious()
  }

  function checkPrevious() {

      if (boxesArr[0] === boxesArr[1]) {
        setSame("Yes")
      } else {
        setSame("No")
    }
    setTimeout(clearBox, 1000)
  }

  function clearBox() {
    setBox(0)
    setTimeout(start, 500)
  }

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Same as previous? {same}</Text>

    <View style={styles.boxes}>
      <View style={{
         width: 100,
         height: 100,
         backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
           {box === 1 ? "Here" : null}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: "red"
       }}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
           {box === 2 ? "Here" : null}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{
         width: 100,
         height: 100,
         backgroundColor: "orange"
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
           {box === 3 ? "Here" : null}
        </Text>
      </View>

    </View>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {hasStarted === false ? start() : null}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "purple", width: 100, marginTop: 10}}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: "center", color: "white"}}>
            Start
          </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    paddingLeft: 8,
    paddingRight: 8,
    paddingTop: 10
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  boxes: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});
```

I assume the problem stems from the comparison made in the "checkPrevious" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the following:

```js
setBoxesArr((prev) => {
  return [num, ...prev]
});
```

doesn't change your `boxesArr` immediately. It is only in the next render of your component that `boxesArr` will hold the new value that you set. That means that when you call `checkPrevious()`, `boxesArr`  is still the old value and not the one you just set. Since the `same` state is derived from your `boxesArr`, I would suggest removing the `checkPrevious()` function and the `same` state and instead calculate it upon the render of your component:

```js
const same = boxesArr[0] === boxesArr[1] ? "Yes" : "No";
```

See example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/9UiyV3oqQ).